# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined", Axios, Vue.JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component, vuex

I am getting this strange error from Vue when trying to access get request from api using axios,
I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

[image]

```
 <template>
    <div class="home">
        <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
        <p>Welcome to your new single-page application, built with <a href="https://vuejs.org" target="_blank">Vue.js</a>.</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    var Vue = require('vue');

   // import axios from "axios";

    window.axios=require('axios');
    export default {
        name: 'Home',
        props: {
            msg: String
        },
        component: {
        },   
        mounted: function () {
            alert('Hi ');
            this.axios.get('https://api.github.com/users')
                .then(value => {
                    alert(value);
                         
                });
        }

    };
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: It should be just `axios.get`, not `this.axios.get`. You may see `this.axios` used in some examples but in those cases they have stored `axios` on `this`, which doesn't appear to be the case in your code.

Comment: I also suggest sticking to the `import` approach rather than using `require` and `window`.

Comment: Thank you @skirtle, much appreciate sir :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` does not reference to `window` in your case. A better approach would be importing `axios` in the component:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

A more efficient way is to set it once globally in the `main.js` file:

```
Vue.prototype.$http = axios
```

And using it where ever you want as `this.$http`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and solved it by adding `type="module"`.

Comment: Can you clarify **where/how** exactly you added `type="module"`?